# Switch Div value with class attribute

Tags: javascript

I want to switch value from div to input and submit.

This's my codes so far

HTML

```
    <form id="forms" action="content.php" method="post">
        <input id="foo" type="hidden" value"">
    </form>

    <div class="btn" value="1" width="40" height="40"></div>
    <div class="btn" value="2" width="40" height="40"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function $(v) { 
    return document.getElementById(v); 
}

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {

    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

        btn.getAttribute('value') = $('foo').value;

        $('forms').submit();

    }, false);

}
```

Why it dont work? can't be clicked? thx

Comment: Patrick : i don't use any library. it's pure javascript. i ever do this and success but i forgot it now.

Comment: Rachel : what u wants me to clarify?

Comment: when you address someone, please use the @ symbol and type in their name (sometimes you will be prompted with an autocomplete). Otherwise, I don't see the message til i revisit the question. FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing the assignment wrong. You need to assign the value of the div button to your hidden foo field. Also, btn is the array of all buttons, you can use *this* inside event handler callback to reference the button that was clicked since this context is bound to the element that has the attached event. I think the following is what you want:

```
(function() {
  function $(v) {
    return document.getElementById(v);
  }


  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      // assign what was clicked (this) to the foo hidden value
      $('foo').value = this.getAttribute('value');
      // now submit
      $('forms').submit();

    }, false);

  }
}());
```

**Edit:** Example using Array's forEach instead (which I assume would be available in your execution environment since you are using *getElementsByClassName* method.

```
(function() {
  function $(v) {
    return document.getElementById(v);
  }


  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

  // each element of the array is passed to the provided callback
  buttons.forEach(function (button) {

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {

      // assign what was clicked (this) to the foo hidden value
      $('foo').value = this.getAttribute('value');
      // now submit
      $('forms').submit();

    }, false);

  });

}());
```

Comment: It's works but i still don't know what is this. (function(){} () )

Comment: Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). It keeps your global scope clean. Not necessary, but just trying to keep the code cleaner. Also suggest using array forEach rather than for loop. Will add to post to show that.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what the purpose of this is,
but if you insist on using divs as radio buttons or w.e 
use data attributes,

like so

```
<div id="div1" data-value="1"></div>
```

and you can use jquery to get the attribute like this:

```
var div1 = $('#div1').data('value')
```

or

```
var div1 = $('#div1').attr('data-value');
```

on click listeners also with jquery

```
$('#div1').on('click', function(){
    // do your thing here
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think `div`s should have a `value` attribute. Maybe you should switch it to `data-value`, which can be used easily in jQuery:

```
<form id="forms" action="content.php" method="post">
    <input id="foo" type="hidden" value"">
</form>

<div class="btn" data-value="1" width="40" height="40"></div>
<div class="btn" data-value="2" width="40" height="40"></div>
```

As for the javascript:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).data('value', $('#foo').val());
    $('#forms').submit();
});
```